# Parse implementation for Facebook login crashes app

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I use Parse for my project. but for some reason the app crashes without any error shown.

I have followed the instructions from the Parse docs.
What am I missing here?

I have tried read and try out some of the suggestions from similar posts but without any luck

I have all the newest api's and included them in my lib and gradel.

My **MainActivity.java**

```
        import com.parse.LogInCallback;
        import com.parse.Parse;
        import com.parse.ParseException;
        import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
        import com.parse.ParseObject;
        import com.parse.ParseUser;

        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            //Defining Variables
            private Toolbar toolbar;
            private NavigationView navigationView;
            private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


                List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");

                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        }
                    }
                });     
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

                // Enable Local Datastore.
                Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

                Parse.initialize(this, "G************X", "P************Q");

                //Testing connection to parse    
                ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
                testObject.put("foo", "bar");
                testObject.saveInBackground();
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gapp.rider" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider4*******7"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity

            android:name="gapp.rider.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting Facebook account in settings? It may be somehow caused by Facebook token things. Try that out first.

Comment: In settings? sorry I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Please dismiss my earlier comment as I've messed up with iOS. On Android, I think should check your manifest. There might be something wrong with some properties.

Comment: i have included my manifest.xml in the question.

Comment: I found that the app does not crash if i remove this line of code:
 ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);

but the Parse docs says:
Add the following where you initialize the Parse SDK in your Application.onCreate():

ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(context);

so am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: It is still extreemly unstable the app. and there is no facebook functions

Comment: Not sure but I'd go to check settings on https://developers.facebook.com for the app again. There might be the key hash not set properly. Both key hashes for release and debug version need to be set in app developer console. You may have set the key hash for the debug environment only. Try to ensure this part again. I can't see anything wrong in your code and I assume you've followed the docs correctly.

Comment: I actually had set the debug wrong. So thanks for that. But unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Alright now I've just come up another idea you may try. I'm not Android user but there must be somewhere that you can wipe out Facebook account like in iOS settings as I mentioned in my first comment that it might clear the token.

Comment: You mist call Parse.initialize(..) before everything

Comment: @Aashir - thanks. I fixed this - but it still wont call the functions.

I think I need to rewrite the whole thing.